# Listen to RabbitMQ queue and get notifications on events

Tags: java, queue, rabbitmq, listener, spring-amqp

I am currently developing an Java application using Spring AMQP with RabbitMQ and would like to monitor my queues and being informed if some events happen, like

- element was *added* to queue,
- element was *removed*, or
- element was but in the queue again (*rollback*).

How can I listen to such events, or what is the RabbitMQ-way of doing such things?

Comment: What do you mean by "element"? "message"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: I could not understand the Use case for getting notification on `message removed`. Could you please explain further.

Comment: @Shirish I want create a monitoring application which shows which messages went into the queue, were taken from the queue and also which went back into the queue, because of a rollback of the transaction.
Hence, I want to show the current status/messages of the queue (e.g. on a UI) and I want to get updates/notifications, whenever the status of the queue changes. (e.g. so that I can update the UI).

Answer (score 0):

To receive a message asynchronously from a queue is to use the annotated listener endpoint infrastructure. In a nutshell, it allows you to expose a method of a managed bean as a Rabbit listener endpoint.

```
@Component
public class MyService {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "myQueue")
    public void processOrder(String data) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Check [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/_reference.html#async-annotation-driven) 
Whenever there a message is pushed to the queue `myQueue` `processOrder` method is triggered.

For your other requirements you can also use [spring events](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2) to monitor any operation performed on the queue. Just right before performing any operation on the queue a respective event will be triggered.

Comment: Do you mean setting up an event system to watch my own methods which perform actions on the queue? If yes, this is also the workaround I did to get the desired behaviour, but sadly this does not anwer my question.

Comment: no processOrder is the method which receives anything which is added to the queue. This method acts like a subscriber not a publisher to the queue. Check the Spring AMqp docs.